# Would granting every PC the choice of a feat or a cantrip be unbalancing?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, house-rules

This [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102304/would-it-hurt-racial-balance-if-every-pc-gets-a-bonus-feat-at-level-1) and the accepted answer are of the opinion that granting an extra feat to all PCs at level 1 does not affect game balance.

Would granting every PC the choice of a feat or a cantrip (as opposed to a feat only) be unbalancing?

I recognize that in some cases characters get racial cantrips, in which case, this house-rule extra cantrip would be in addition to racially granted ones.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### No.

Since the Feat Magic Initiate grants 2 cantrips, giving the choice of gaining a single cantrip instead would be worse than granting a Feat.

Comment: Excellent observation.  With my mod, a character could take a free house-rule cantrip at level 1, then Magic Initiate instead of an ASI, and with the potential for racial and class cantrips, end up cantripy as heck.  That would be alright.

Comment: @Jack If you are worried about a character with many cantrips you may be interested in checking [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88225/33707)

Comment: While true, this doesn't really answer the question. "Would it unbalance the game?" is the question, not "would anyone pick a cantrip over a feat?".

Comment: @Jack You're missing the point... Given the choice between "a feat" and "a cantrip", nobody in their right mind would take the cantrip, because there is a feat that allows a more than just that. The existence of Magic Initiate indicates that a feat is more valuable than a single cantrip. Your game would become slightly unbalanced in favor of the people who took the feat.

Comment: @Sdjz That's a good link.  I'm good with all PCs having one more cantrip than they would otherwise, I'm just looking for what I might not have considered in terms of something that would somehow take something special some class or subclass or race or subrace.

Comment: @T.J.L. I see your point.  Why take one cantrip, when you can have two?  I suppose the only reason would be to take a cantrip at level one and then Magic Initiate as a feat at the right opportunity and get three.  But good point.

Comment: @Jack I doubt anybody is going to be that desperate for that many cantrips and not just *be* a spell caster. I mean... I've made a character with a cantrip for every kind of damage, but it's really not that good a build.

Comment: It might be good to edit some of what @T.J.L. is saying into your answer if you agree. There's good stuff there that could improve what you have currently. Also, I do think answering the title question is also a good idea.

Comment: I feel like this isn't actually an answer to the question. just a problem with the question that should have really been a comment.

Comment: One way I can see the single cantrip being a good alternative is if the player can choose the ability to use for casting instead of being restricted the casting ability of the chosen class for Magic Initiate.

Comment: @goodguy5 The answer to the question is "no", and thus proven ny a simple example. Doubtless there may be some edge case, but there is no simple way to evaluate how unbalanced a single cantrip gained at high level vs another feat or ASI..

Comment: It might be worth clarifying the header, as there's another yes/no question in the body of the question that's phrased slightly differently.

Comment: @T.J.L. I think you're right.  That makes it pointless to offer a cantrip in addition.